# How can I update my for loop to output my parameter URL key value pairs?

Tags: javascript, analytics

I have a block of code that outputs each of the key value pairs found in a query string, of a parameter URL.

My questions is, I wish to update the code block in order to send through the standard utm parameters as properties in an the analytics.track() call. Additional requirements are:

- Send only officially supported utm parameters as properties
- Send only utm parameters included in the URL query string (i.e. don't send null utm parameters)
- Name the track call: "User Referred"

```
    var output = {};
    var qs = document.location.search.substring(1);
    qs = qs.split('&');

    for (var i = 0; i < qs.length; i++) {
        var tokens = qs[i].split('=');
      output[tokens[0].toLowerCase()] = tokens[1];
    }

    return output;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no need for all this string parsing in late 2019. There are [built-ins](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/searchParams) to do this stuff.

```
let output = (new URL(document.location)).searchParams;
for (const [key, value] of output) {
  console.log(key, '=', value);
}
```

Comment: I'd personally use [`URLSearchParams.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/forEach) over [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of).

Comment: The string parsing is required of my code block. But thank you regardless!